# Merge multiple fields into one using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a question about merging multiple nodes into one node. But i couldnt figure out how to do this.

I have the following XML file:

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
               xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
               xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
               xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>
            <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
                <TicketUpdates>
                    <TicketUpdate>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>9876</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Yes</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>8765</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Fiber</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <Id>1234</ticketId>
                        <Status>New</status>
                    </TicketUpdate>
                    <TicketUpdate>
                        <TicketUpdate>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>6823</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>No</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>3453</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Fiber</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <Id>2343</ticketId>
                        <Status>Update</status>
                    </TicketUpdate>
                </TicketUpdates>
            </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
        </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I would like to merge the FreeFields nodes into 1 nodes like the following and create the following output:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
               xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
               xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
               xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>
            <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
                <TicketUpdates>
                    <TicketUpdate>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>9876</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Yes</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>8765</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Fiber</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>7654</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>https://www.stackoverflow.com</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <Id>1234</ticketId>
                        <Status>New</status>
                    </TicketUpdate>
                    <TicketUpdate>
                        <TicketUpdate>
                        <FreeFields>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>6823</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>No</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>3453</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>Fiber</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                            <FreeField>
                                <FreeFieldID>8563</FreeFieldID>
                                <Value>https://www.stackexchange.com</Value>
                            </FreeField>
                        </FreeFields>
                        <Id>2343</ticketId>
                        <Status>Update</status>
                    </TicketUpdate>
                </TicketUpdates>
            </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
        </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to use an xsl:for-each. and copy it to a new list, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this.
Could someone please help me with an example?
I tried googling for the solution but was unable to find a solution.

**Update 1** 
This is the XSLT I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <!-- Stylesheet to inject namespaces into a document in specific places -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>

          <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Handle 'Root' wrapper added by JSON to XML policy -->
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(/Root)">
              <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
              </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- If the root element is not what was in the schema, add it -->
            <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(/RetrieveTicketUpdates))">
              <RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
              </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResult>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- everything checks out,  just copy the xml-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </RetrieveTicketUpdatesResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/FreeFields/*/FreeField" name="copy-freefields">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Root/*" name="copy-root">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(local-name()='Root') and not(local-name()='Array')]" name="copy-all">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Note also that both the input and output you show us are missing a namespace declaration binding the `soap` prefix to a namespace URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="TicketUpdate">
    <xsl:copy>
      <FreeFields>
        <xsl:copy-of select="FreeFields/FreeField"/>
      </FreeFields>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'FreeFields']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You have also to correct some errors in your source XML.

Comment: Tnx! :) my source XML was bigger and stripped out a lot of extra nodes. i think i didn't edit it correctly. your solution works like a charm